# Rails + JQuery: Why is my image not showing up, but showing the alt text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to disable my form submit button and display an image spinner.  Instead of displaying my image though, it displays the alt text for the image.  Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I am using Rails 3.0.3 and JQuery 1.4.4

Here is my HAML code

```
#spinner 

:javascript
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        $('#spinner').empty().html('Chargement de votre document... #{image_tag 'spinning-wait.gif'} ');
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })
```

Here is the HTML that it generates:

```
      <div id='spinner'></div>
      </form>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
            $('#form').submit(function(){
              $('#spinner').empty().html('Chargement de votre document... <img alt="Spinning-wait" src="/images/spinning-wait.gif?1296407417" /> ');
              $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            })
        //]]>
      </script>
```

## spinner is compiled to  and the :javascript part is placed in script tags

Comment: what is the browser and are you using SSL (https) ?

Comment: ehh.. Firefox 4 beta 10, on linux..  no SSL

Answer (score 1):

make sure your path/to/image is right

Comment: yeah, when I load it through curl, it seems to work fine, and plus its just in my public/images directory.. so nothing funky going on there.

Comment: still not convinced...try using the absolute url.